# Why are my cells appearing blank in my UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a little bit of an odd structure for my `UITableView`. Basically, I have `ArticleCell` objects (subclass of `UITableViewCell`) that make up the table, and each `ArticleCell` is comprised of a "front" view and a "back" view. The front view has all the labels and whatnot the user sees, while the back has two icons to the left and right. This two view idea is so the user can slide the top view to the right or left to quickly select an option (kind of like in Reeder).

I've implemented this slightly in the storyboard, but mostly in code. The only thing I did in the storyboard was have the layout of the `UITableViewController` done, and I named the identifier for the prototype cell (identifier: "ArticleCell").

Other than the storyboard, as I said, everything's done in code. I get the cell's information from Core Data, and construct the cell by setting the article to the cell's `article` property, which then sets that article to `CellFront` `UIView`'s `article` property. Because there's two kinds of cell layouts depending on the type of article the cell holds, in `CellFront` it checks when kind of cell it is (a property called `isUserAddedText`) and creates the layout accordingly.

But as I said, nothing's showing up when the app loads, all the cells load and I can tap them to go to their content, but the cells themselves are blank.

The relevant code is as follows:

Cell Data Source:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    ArticleInfo *articleInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ArticleCell";

    ArticleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ArticleCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.article = articleInfo;

    return cell;
}
```

In `ArticleCell.m`, I overrode article's set method so when the data source method above calls it, it could set the view's `article` property as well.

```
- (void)setArticle:(ArticleInfo *)article {
    _article = article;

    self.cellFront.article = article;
}
```

I also created the `CellFront` and `CellBack` `UIView`s in the `ArticleCell.m` file:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.cellBack = [[CellBack alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 80)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.cellBack];

    self.cellFront = [[CellFront alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 80)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.cellFront];
}
```

`CellFront.m` then calls the following method inside its `initWithFrame:` method, which sets up the labels depending on the kind of article and adds them to the subview.

```
- (void)addControlsToView {
    if ([self.article.isUserAddedText isEqualToNumber:@YES]) {
        UILabel *preview = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 280, 70)];
        preview.text = self.article.preview;
        preview.numberOfLines = 4;
        preview.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
        preview.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        preview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:preview];
    }
    else {
        UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 280, 20)];
        title.text = self.article.title;
        title.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f];
        title.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:title];

        UILabel *URL = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 35, 280, 20)];
        URL.text = self.article.url;
        URL.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
        URL.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        URL.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:URL];

        UILabel *preview = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 60, 280, 40)];
        preview.text = self.article.preview;
        preview.numberOfLines = 2;
        preview.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
        preview.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        preview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:preview];
    }
}
```

That's everything I thought would be relevant to include. Why exactly are all the cells showing up blank?

Comment: In the storyboard, did you set the Custom Class of the prototype table view cell to `ArticleCell`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are **not using storyboard** or NIB's to define your views, `awakeFromNib:` will never be called.

Here is some [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/)

You should try overriding `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` instead of `awakeFromNib:`

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self != nil) {
        // DO STUFF
    }

    return self;
}
```

If you are trying to **use a storyboard** then you are dequeueing the cells incorrectly, replace:

```
ArticleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ArticleCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

With:

```
ArticleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This method will initialize a new cell from the storyboard if there is not one in the queue. The method you were using won't. This means that cell will equal nil sometimes, then you initialize a new cell with the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method, which will not call the `awakeFromNib` because you are not decoding it from the NIB.

Here is a link to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier%3aforIndexPath%3a) for this method.

---

**Additional Information**

You will also not see the data in the cell because you are setting the label text values in the same block of code that you using to initialize the views. Basically, you need to do:

```
...
preview.text = self.article.preview;
...
```

...this part of the `addControlsToView` method every time the cell is reused, and the initialization of the UILabel only once. I would move the above code into a setter for the article property on `CellFront`. For example, first declare some properties for the labels

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *preview1Label;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *URLLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *preview2Label;
```

Then something like this to initialize the controls

```
- (void)initControls {
    self.preview1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 280, 70)];
    self.preview1.text = self.article.preview;
    self.preview1.numberOfLines = 4;
    self.preview1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
    self.preview1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.preview1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self addSubview:self.preview1];

    self.title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 280, 20)];
    self.title.text = self.article.title;
    self.title.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f];
    self.title.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self addSubview:self.title];

    self.URL = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 35, 280, 20)];
    self.URL.text = self.article.url;
    self.URL.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
    self.URL.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.URL.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self addSubview:self.URL];

    self.preview2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 60, 280, 40)];
    self.preview2.text = self.article.preview;
    self.preview2.numberOfLines = 2;
    self.preview2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
    self.preview2.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.preview2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self addSubview:self.preview2];
}
```

Then something like this to set the controls, likely from the setter of the article property.

```
- (void)setControls {
    if ([self.article.isUserAddedText isEqualToNumber:@YES]) {
        self.preview1.hidden = NO;
        self.preview1.text = self.article.preview;
        self.title.hidden = YES;
        self.title.text = nil;
        self.URL.hidden = YES;
        self.URL.text = nil;
        self.preview2.hidden = YES;
        self.preview2.text = nil;
    }
    else {
        self.preview1.hidden = YES;
        self.preview1.text = nil;
        self.title.hidden = NO;
        self.title.text = self.article.title;
        self.URL.hidden = NO;
        self.URL.text = self.article.url;
        self.preview2.hidden = NO;
        self.preview2.text = self.article.preview;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a storyboard or a NIB as well as the code that you posted?

Comment: Yes, see the second paragraph.

Comment: Sorry, missed that and assumed that because of the dequeue method you were using and because you were creating all the objects in code anyway that you were not using a storyboard. I edited my answer.

Comment: That unfortunately seemed to do nothing.

Comment: If you can send me the project or a link to the source code I will take a look.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm comfortable sending the full project, is there a specific portion you'd like?

Comment: It's just hard to debug storyboards. If you wanna send me the storyboard and the controller in question I can take a look at where the issue is.

Comment: I've sent them to the email address listed on your website. Thanks again.

Comment: My apologies, that email was not correct so I didn't get your email. Thanks for finding a bug :) Anyway, I updated the site, you can use the updated email or the one I have listed on my profile here.